# Unity - prevent occlusion culling with far objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, occlusion

In Unity, I'm having a scene where objects are far from each other but they are visible from each other in unity editor. But when i play in the game mode they are not visible and gets generated when player gets close to them.

I have set off the occlusion culling in scene camera as well as from the main camera inspector.

Any method how to prevent this? My example game is [here](https://mega.nz/file/qFgwjYrD#GyeTWgqMzK6lzhAul85hVTqb38EHqxn8Omi3znb4p9Q). The player has to keep pressing the up arrow ⬆️ button to play the game.

All the objects are getting generated after reaching near them.

Comment: Maybe has something to do with the camera clipping parameter?

Answer (score 0):

set the main camera and the scene camera clipping panes to 10000

[image]